# Unite Gallery questions with mp4 and vtt

Tags: javascript, mp4, vtt

Two questions on Unite Gallery Javascript package. Thanking you all in advance.
I have only Mp4 file and dont have OGV and WEBM files. When I tried html5video mode with Unite Gallery, I hear only audio. No video. The file plays fine if I do it on browser standalone. How do I overcome this challenge?
Second question: How do I incorporate VTT with the Mp4 video in Unite Gallery? I have VTT file and in VLC it works together well.

Looking for your answers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please limit your post to one question and include a [mcve] of your code so that people may help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.